# печать страницы нажатием enter

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть вот такой код, который при нажатии кнопки выводит в новой вкладке шаблон на печать. стоит задача делать то же самое, но при нажатии кнопки enter.

```html
<?php
include('template.php');
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$data ="Текст на печать";
$tpl = new template('./temp','.tpl'); 
$tpl -> load('print'); 
$tpl -> vars('print',array('data')); 
echo $tpl -> out('print'); 
} else {
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post" onsubmit="window.open('','myprt', 'width=600, height=400, left=0, top=0')" target="myprt">
<br><button name="Submit" >Распечатать</button>
</form>
<?php
}
```

Для этого использую вот такой код.

```html
    <form method="POST" action="" id="form_who_should_be_checked">
<input name="anything" value="text">
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById("form_who_should_be_checked").onsubmit= 
 function() {
  alert(this.anything.value);
  return false;
 }
</script>
```

По отдельности они работают а вот вместе не могу совместить.

Comment: Два примера по отдельности никак не связаны и делают разные вещи. Что в итоге хотите увидеть?

Comment: в итоге очень хочется выводить печать нажатием клавиши enter- ввел в текстовое поле текст и нажал enter без всяких кнопок на форме

Comment: неужели никто не поможет?

Comment: При нажании enter-а, когда фокус в поле ввода форма тоже отправляется (chromium).

Comment: это замечательно но мне же нужно еще вывести шаблон на печать

Comment: так в первом варианте (onsubmit) должно и от кнопки работать и от enter-а, какая разница как форму отправлять

Comment: не хочет. точнее при начальной загрузке страницы не работает а если нажать один раз на кнопку то потом работает. да и в любом случае мне нужно что бы отсутствовала кнопка а была только форма ввода

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии enter-а на основной клавиатуре отправится форма `myform`

```
    <form action="blabla" id="myform">
      <input type="hidden" name="enter_or_button" value="enter"/>
      <input type="text" name="sample_submit_enter"/>
    </form>


    <script>
      document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === 13)
          document.getElementById('myform').submit();
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: да кажется у меня большие проблемы. дело в том что я использую аякс для запроса данных без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: вместо `document.getElementById('myform').submit();` используйте свой код для ajax-запроса. Форма тут не обязательна.

Answer (score 0):

эх все оказалось гораздо проще -

```js
<script>
document.getElementById("send_ajax").onsubmit= 
function() {
     $.ajax ({
     url: 'ajax.php',
     type: 'post',
     data: {'data':this.anything.value},
     success:function(data){
 $('#result').html(data);
        window.open('print.php?data='+data,'myprt', 'width=600, height=400, left=0, top=0');
 }
        })
        this.anything.value="";   
        return false;
} 
</script>
```

и далее в print.php уже парсим и шаблонизируем и печатаем

Comment: а где тут **отправить нажатием enter** ?

Comment: <form id="send_ajax">
<br><input type="text" name="anything" id="autofocus" autofocus autocomplete="off">
</form> сделал что бы скрипт ajax.php отправлял данные в формате json а скрипт print.php их парсит

Comment: это автофокус на поле для ввода, которым и так можно форму отправить, нажав enter, о чем я и писал  
ладно, если разобрались с проблемой, значит всё окей.